# JS working in Chrome but not Firefox

Tags: javascript, wordpress, firefox

This script stopped working in FireFox a couple of weeks ago, around the time I added an SSL certificate to the site. I've confirmed that SSL is being used everywhere, and I've tried disabling all recently installed plugins, to no avail.

I've looked at it with Web Console and don't see any errors there either - though I'm not very experienced with that.

I've also looked at other threads here about js working in Chrome but not FF, but none of the proposed solutions seem to apply to my script.

The problem is that the js is apparently not being called at all - it should show up between the introduction and the "share" graphic.

Any ideas?

This is the page where it should show up, between the text and the "share" graphic: [Quiz](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/quizzes-and-tests/partitive-article-quiz/)

And this is the js file: [Javascript](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/wp-content/themes/cassie/js/quiz-partitive-article.js)

Here is the code:

```
$.each(questions, function (key, value) { 
//console.log( key + ": " + value.question );        question = value.question;
    qtype = value.qtype;
    opts = value.opts;
    answer = value.answer;
    special = value.special;        $('#quiz-form').append('<p>&#160;<br>' + parseInt(key + 1) + ") " + question + '</p>');        if (qtype == "radio")
{       opt_array = opts.split(',');       for (i = 0; i < opt_array.length; i++)
{      $('#quiz-form').append('<p><input data-ftype="radio" type="radio" name="question_' + key + '" class="question_' + key + '" value="' + opt_array[i] + '"> ' + opt_array[i] + ' </p>');           }
} else if (qtype == "checkbox"}
else if (qtype == "checkbox")
{
   opt_array = opts.split(',');
   for (i = 0; i<opt_array.length;i++)
{
    $('#quiz-form').append('<p><input data-ftype="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="question_' + key + '" class="question_' + key + '" value="'+ opt_array[i] + '"> ' + opt_array[i] + '</p>');
}
}
    else if (qtype == "input")
{

    $('#quiz-form').append('<p><input data-ftype="text" name="question_' + key + '" type="text" class="question_' + key + '" value="" style = "border:1px solid"  ></p>');
}        $('#quiz-form').append('<p><input name="answer_' + key + '" type="hidden" value="' + answer + '" class="answer_' + key + '"   ></p>');
    $('#quiz-form').append('<p class="special" id="special_' + key + '" ><strong>Correct answer(s): ' + answer + '</strong> » Explanation: ' + special + '</p>');
});
    $('#quiz-form').append('<p>All done? Check your answers: <input name="submit" id="submit" type="button" value="Submit"></p>');        $('#quiz-form').append('<p>Want another chance? <input name="refresh" id="refresh" type="button" value="Start over"></p>');        $( "#quiz-form" ).on( "click", "#submit", function() {


quest_numb = questions.length;

user_answers = new Array();
real_answers = new Array();   
for (i = 0; i <quest_numb;i++) 

{

if ($("input[name ='question_" + i + "']").data('ftype')=='radio')     {       user_answers.push($(":input[type='radio'][name ='question_" + i + "']:checked").val());      }      if ($("input[name ='question_" + i + "']").data('ftype')=='text') {       user_answers.push($(":input[type='text'][name ='question_" + i + "']").val());      }      if ($("input[name ='question_" + i + "']").data('ftype')=='checkbox') {
  var chkArray = [];
     $(".question_" + i + ":checked").each(function() {
  chkArray.push($(this).val());
 });   var selected = chkArray.join(',')
 user_answers.push(selected);      }        real_answers.push($(":input[type='hidden'][name ='answer_" + i + "']").val());      // alert($(":input[type='text'][name ='question_"+i+"']").val());

 }

 points=0;
 message='<div id="results">';
 inc=1;
 for(i=0;i<real_answers.length;i++) {
 if (typeof user_answers[i]=='undefined' || user_answers[i]=='') 
{   //message+='<p>'+parseInt(i+1) + ')' +' You didn't answer this     question.</p>';
  $('#special_'+i).text(i+inc+') '+'You didn\'t answer this question.');
  $('#special_'+i).show();
  $(":input[name ='question_"+i+"']").prop('disabled',true);
 }

  else if( user_answers[i].toLowerCase().trim()==real_answers[i]) 
  {


points++;
//message+='<p>' +parseInt(i+1)  + ')' +' Très bien !</p>';
$('#special_'+i).text(i+inc+') '+'Très bien !');
  $('#special_'+i).addClass('correct');
  $('#special_'+i).show();

 }   else 
 {

  $('#special_'+i).text($('#special_'+i).text().replace(i+inc+') '+' ',''));
  $('#special_'+i).prepend(i+inc+') '+' ');
  $('#special_'+i).show();
 }

 }
 message+='<p> Your score: ' + points + '/' + real_answers.length + '</p>';percent=points*100/real_answers.length;if(percent>=90) 
 {
   message+='<p> Chapeau !</p>';

 }
 if(percent>=80 && percent<90) 
 {
 message+='<p> Très bien !</p>';

 }if(percent>=60 && percent<80) 
 {
 message+='<p> Pas mal.</p>';

 }if(percent>=40 && percent<60) 
 {
 message+='<p> Houp ! Il faut étudier un peu plus.</p>';

 }
 if(percent<40) 
 {
   message+='<p> Oh là là - il faut étudier !</p>';

}message+='</div>';
    $('#quiz-form #results').remove();
    $('#quiz-form').prepend(message);
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");

 });
    $( "#quiz-form" ).on( "click", "#refresh", function() {
 location.reload();
 window.scrollTo(0,0);
 });
});function getQueryVariable(variable)
{
       var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
   var vars = query.split("&");
   for (var i = 0; i<vars.length;i++) {
           var pair = vars[i].split("=");
           if (pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
   }
       return(false);
 }
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Check the console. You have a load of errors appearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous JS errors occurring throughout your code. First and foremost, you need to fix the insecure file references, since you are using SSL, so files like this will not load - either change it to relative paths or replace http with https:

```
<script src="http://www.feedblitz.com/js/tinybox2/tinybox.js" type="text/javascript">
```

If you are unsure how to view these errors in your browser, please refer to any of these articles:

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Tools/Web_Console